# Will this series of functions converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $f(t)$ be continuous in $\Bbb{R}$.
Applying the product rule for integration inductively to $$e^{at}\, \int f(t)\, e^{-at}\, dt,$$ one gets the series $$-{1 \over a} \biggl( f(t)+{1\over a} f’(t)+{1\over a^2} f’’(t)+{1\over a^3} f’’’(t)+\cdots \biggr).$$

Question: Does this series always converge to the original expression? If not, under what conditions will it converge?

Comment: You should include your assumptions in your problem statement.  For example, what is the domain of integration, the sign of $a$?

Comment: @D.B. Not necessarily integrable in closed form though.

Comment: I suppose a good starting point would be to ask what type of convergence you are looking for (ie: pointwise, L^2).

Comment: @D.B. I don’t know what that is.

Comment: Well, in your series after integrating by parts, you have derivatives of all orders.  If these are clasical derivatives, it looks like you would need pointwise convergence.  If these are weak derivatives, you might be looking for L^2 convergence.

Comment: @D.B. Yes, they are classical derivatives.

Comment: I mean the derivatives which we first get used to.

Comment: What do you think then will the answer be?

Comment: Ok.  So one condition for convergence is for all the derivatives to be bounded on $\mathbb{R}$.  Look up the Weierstrass M-test to determine an upper bound for the derivatives.  If all the derivatives are bounded above so that the power series converges, then you would have uniform convergence.

Comment: Are you assuming $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ to be smooth with compact support so the boundary term comes only from $t$ and not the other endpoint of integration?

Comment: @user10354138 Sorry, I don’t understand what you’re talking about. Anyways, I’ve changed $\Bbb{C}$ to $\Bbb{R}$ to make things simpler (if possible!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we pick, for instance - $f(t)=e^{at}$, we get the series - 
$$-{1 \over a} \biggl( e^{at}+ e^{at}+ e^{at}+\cdots \biggr)$$

This series does not converge.

BUT! if you know that all of the derivatives of $f(t)$ are uniformly bounded, then you can use the Weierstrass M-test and conclude that the series does converge (even uniformly). In my example, the derivativs were not uniformly bounded, and the series indeed did not converge.